# How to put an image in lightbox beneath the image?

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, elementor

On my Wordpress website (with Elementor) I want to show that when user opens lightbox the image is loading. I thought the easiest way would be to put very small image that says "loading" first and when the image is loaded it will cover the "loading". Because otherwise my lightbox is black and user might click away. Is there any simple way to do this with extra CSS for example?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for my lightbox by just adding extra CSS to the theme:

```
.bdt-lightbox{
background-image: url("loading.png");
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```